# Php Array Key Exist but it is impossible to access element giving

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, offset

I have created this array in php;

```
array(21) { [0]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(0) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "在" } [1]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(20) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(1) "P" } [2]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(40) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "中" } [3]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(60) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "使用" } [4]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(80) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "类型" } [5]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(100) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "工具" } [6]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(120) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "时" } [7]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(140) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "有" } [8]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(160) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "几" } [9]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(180) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "种" } [10]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(200) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "方法" } [11]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(220) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "可以" } [12]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(240) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "确保" } [13]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(260) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "您" } [14]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(280) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "能够" } [15]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(300) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "以" } [16]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(320) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "所" } [17]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(340) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(3) "选" } [18]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(360) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "格式" } [19]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(380) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "对齐" } [20]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> int(400) ["y"]=> int(0) ["t"]=> string(6) "文本" } }
```

As you can see it gives a 22 vector and each element has x y t subarray. I checked the keys

```
array(21) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) [6]=> int(6) [7]=> int(7) [8]=> int(8) [9]=> int(9) [10]=> int(10) [11]=> int(11) [12]=> int(12) [13]=> int(13) [14]=> int(14) [15]=> int(15) [16]=> int(16) [17]=> int(17) [18]=> int(18) [19]=> int(19) [20]=> int(20) }
```

But it is not able to asset example element 3; giving offset notice
Here is the code

```
<?php 
$url = "https://pinyin-rest.pepebecker.com/hanzi/".urlencode("");
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL ,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//var_dump($data,$url);
$chars= json_decode($data);
$svgChinese = array();
$i = 0;
$cpt =0;
foreach ($chars as $one){
    if ( is_object($one)):
    $svgChinese[$cpt]["x"]= $i;
    $svgChinese[$cpt]["y"]= $y;
    $svgChinese[$cpt]["t"]= $one->simplified;
    $cpt++;
    $i+=20;
    endif;
}

var_dump($svgChinese);
var_dump(array_keys($svgChinese));
var_dump($svgChinese[3]); // error here

?>
```

You change the `curl` part with this: this is to text online:

```
$chars= json_decode('[[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}],[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}],[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}],[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}],[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}],[{"traditional":"哦","definitions":{"e2":{"pinyin":"é","translations":["to chant"],"zhuyin":"ㄜˊ"},"o2":{"pinyin":"ó","translations":["oh (interjection indicating doubt or surprise)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛˊ"},"o4":{"pinyin":"ò","translations":["oh (interjection indicating that one has just learned sth)"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ`"},"o5":{"pinyin":"o","translations":["sentence-final particle that conveys informality, warmth, friendliness or intimacy","may also indicate that one is stating a fact that the other person is not aware of"],"zhuyin":"ㄛ˙"}},"hsk":6,"simplified":"哦"}]]');
```

Comment: What is the exact error? can you post it here?

Comment: The array you have created, is that `$english` ? If so, why are you exploding it?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay 
The error is Php Notice: Undefined index 3

Comment: @Jonathan 
The `$english`  Content English words and is explode to get different world in a vector

Comment: Sample fiddle https://3v4l.org/vPJHp works fine. I suppose you show us not all code.

Comment: Even running with your sentence it is working. So, the problem is in something that you don't show us.

Comment: @u_mulder 
Please check it again

Comment: use this `$url = "https://pinyin-rest.pepebecker.com/hanzi/".urlencode("在Photoshop中使用类型工具时，有几种方法可以确保您能够以所选格式对齐文本。我可以确认以下说明适用于Photoshop CS5和CS6。");` 

it doent work i dont know why.

Comment: @user39464 the problem is that your `$chars= json_decode($data);` is array of arrays so `is_object` is false so the `$svgChinese` array is never added elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$svgEnglish` does not have index 3 as `$cpt` starts from 0 so last element would be `$svgEnglish[2]`

Comment: As I mentioned in the post the array has 22 elements and the `array_keys` return 22 elements , ` 0 to 21`

Comment: @user39464 thats strange, can you create a phpfiddle and share so that we can see the exact scenario

Comment: also please show output of `var_dump($svgEnglish);`